# add images to slider in php. My code just adds one image

Tags: php

my code only shows one image from the database. I dont know whats the problem. I tried looping it with allthe divs and ul but nothing it only shows one image. my code is

```
<div class="fullwidthbanner-container">
            <div class="fullwidthbanner">

                <?php 

            $about = slider();
            while($about_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($about)){ 
        ?> 
                <ul>
                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7">

               <img src="images/<?php echo $about_fetch["slide"];?>" alt="">

                             <?php
            }?>





                    </li>


                </ul>

                <!--<div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>-->

            </div><!-- end .banner -->

        </div><!-- end .bannercontainer -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the code-part, try this please:

(i assume, you dont want to have several `<ul>` elements and only the `<li>`'s)

```
<div class="fullwidthbanner-container">
    <div class="fullwidthbanner">
        <ul>
            <?php 
            $about = slider();
            while($about_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($about)){ ?>
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7">
                    <img src="images/<?php echo $about_fetch["slide"];?>" alt="">
                </li>               
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- end .fullwidthbanner -->
</div><!-- end .fullwidthbanner-container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your HTML isn't valid.  You're looping over the start of a `<ul>` and `<li>` and not closing either until after the loop.

If that isn't the problem, then we can't help you since there is no debugging information available.  Break your problem up into pieces.  Is the issue server-side or client-side?  Look at your output HTML to be sure.  What are the return values of `mysql_fetch_array()` for each iteration?  `var_dump()` is your friend.